# Documenting functional tests

Tags: documentation, e2e-testing

I'm about to start writing e2e tests for a web app i've been working on for the last months. I am currently investigating how to best document these tests. In my company the way it's been done before (on older, non-web programs) is to have a big word document that describes the action of each test, and the expected result. Tests are then run with a third party software, and if any test fail, we can use the documentation to troubleshoot.

This way works fine, but i'm wondering if there is a more efficient, "web-based" way of documenting the e2e tests. We have no prior experience with web-based apps, and my research lead me to observablehq's javascript-based notebooks. I thought maybe it is possible to integrate the actual tests into it, along with the test specifications and then run the codeblocks from there. But i'm not sure this approach is worth the extra effort rather than the current way we do things.

I guess what i'm asking is how other developers are documenting e2e tests for web-based apps, and lessons learned around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use an automation framework that makes you build the tests from a specification. This is typically a markdown file which describes the business case being tested. Each of the steps are executed by the framework. This means that you can re-use the steps as you build out the specifications. An example of this is [Gauge](https://getgauge.io). You can read their [documentation on building specifications](https://docs.gauge.org/writing-specifications.html) to get a better idea of what I mean.

There are a few advantages to following this approach:

1. The specifications are stored alongside the code. This means that the test cases follow the code as it evolves. In the 'old days' where this was stored in documents there was a challenge keeping this in sync with versions of the code.
2. The tests are self documentation the specification both drives the test and documents the test.
3. The test reports are produced in HTML and therefore are easier to understand.

Comment: that would be nice to have such a tool to build complex e2e test cases just from specification, all that said business system are usually complex beasts,

Answer (score 1):

Good documentation is key, when talking about end to end testing it could be a little more challenging. Use cases and its data organization is the first thing to address. You want your test case input and output verification organized in a cohesive way, including specification and use case description.

Some project with e2e test case documentation example:

- [Cloud storage mirror](https://github.com/viant/smirror/tree/master/e2e/regression/cases/001_gs2s3)
- [Cross vendor database synchronizer](https://github.com/viant/dbsync/blob/master/e2e/regression/use_cases/007_delete_merge/description.txt)

Finally you might be interested in [test data organization](https://medium.com/@adrianwit/killing-data-testing-swamp-6c3e11fb92c6)